# Are all dummy variables stationary?

Tags: time-series, binary-data, stationarity, categorical-encoding

If a time series model contained only dummy variables as dependent and independent variables. Is it always stationary?

Comment: Consider a series $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n, \ldots)$ of independent Bernoulli $p^n$ variables for $0\lt p\lt 1.$

Comment: @whuber, do you mean if that if all variables fall in between 0-1 (in the case of binary variable), the value does not progress or change over time; hence, it would be stationary?

Comment: What is your definition of stationary?  There are several different (but closely related) ones.  I believe they all include the requirement that the expectations don't change over time.  Apply that to my example.

Comment: @whuber okay, thank you!

Comment: @whuber My variables are stationary individually by ADF tests, is it safe to use multiple linear regression with ols estimation?

Comment: That comment--which is about data--has so little to do with your question--which is about a model--that I suspect you should change your question entirely.